# array not accepting more than one input

Tags: c#, arrays

So I bought Murach's C# 2015 book just to attempt to start learning some code. I'm currently in one section about array's and I'm stuck. Array only appears to be accepting one input. I need it to take every input from the user and save it, to then regurgitate it in a message box. Have I placed the array correctly and it's for loop correctly?

here is the code bulk

```
public partial class frmInvoiceTotal : Form
{
    public frmInvoiceTotal()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    decimal[] totals = new decimal[5];
    int index = 0;


    // TODO: declare class variables for array and list here

    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {              
                if (txtSubtotal.Text == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(
                        "Subtotal is a required field.", "Entry Error");
                }
                else
                {
                for (index = 0; index < totals.Length; index++)    //this the correct spot for the for loop?
                {

                    decimal subtotal = Decimal.Parse(txtSubtotal.Text);
                    totals[index] = subtotal;
                    if (subtotal > 0 && subtotal < 10000)
                    {
                        decimal discountPercent = 0m;
                        if (subtotal >= 500)
                            discountPercent = .2m;
                        else if (subtotal >= 250 & subtotal < 500)
                            discountPercent = .15m;
                        else if (subtotal >= 100 & subtotal < 250)
                            discountPercent = .1m;
                        decimal discountAmount = subtotal * discountPercent;
                        decimal invoiceTotal = subtotal - discountAmount;


                        discountAmount = Math.Round(discountAmount, 2);
                        invoiceTotal = Math.Round(invoiceTotal, 2);

                        txtDiscountPercent.Text = discountPercent.ToString("p1");
                        txtDiscountAmount.Text = discountAmount.ToString();
                        txtTotal.Text = invoiceTotal.ToString();
                    }



                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(
                            "Subtotal must be greater than 0 and less than 10,000.",
                            "Entry Error");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(
                "Please enter a valid number for the Subtotal field.",
                "Entry Error");
        }
        txtSubtotal.Focus();

    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("totals\n" + totals[0]  + "\n"+ totals[1] + "\n" + totals[2] + 
            "\n" + totals[3] + "\n" + totals[4], "test");
        //string totalsString = "";
        //foreach (int index in totals)            
            //totalsString += subtotal + "\n";
            //MessageBox.Show("The totals are:\n" +
                //totalsString + "\n", "Order Totals");

        // TODO: add code that displays dialog boxes here

        this.Close();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Also sorry if I didn't send it correctly, I've never posted here before

Comment: `totals.length` is always 0 when it gets to the `for` loop, so it will only ever loop once.

Comment: So does that mean the for loop has to move higher?

Comment: Moving it higher isn't going to do any good. You need to add values to your array, or iterate over something else.

Comment: Doesn't totals[index] = subtotal; give it the values needed? and it just loops from there? I think I'm missing something small, lol.

Comment: You can't loop on something you're adding in the loop. I don't know what exactly you're trying to do, but if you just need to iterate 5 times, as simpler loop would use `index < 5`...

Comment: "I need it to take every input from the user (...)". What UI did you have in mind? Pocket calculator-like (user entering each individual value in the same input field, one after the other)? List view (e.g. multiple input fields on the same form)? Comma-separated (all values together in a single field)?

Comment: Basically I need to be able to enter in 5 sub totals, and each entry be stored into a part of the array, then at the end when I click exit I need a message box to display the 5 subtotals that were typed in. Right now it just displays one entry 5 times

Comment: just one entry per line, just keeping it simple

Comment: @AustinD One entry per line - do you mean to say `txtSubtotal` is a multi-line text box, where the user can enter all values together?

Comment: The only value the user enters is the subtotal, everything else is generated, but I do need what the user types in to display in the message box after hitting exit.

Comment: @AustinD There is no such thing as "_the_ subtotal", as there can be up to 5. Therefore, my initial question about the UI still stands. Keep in mind that in real life, a 'form' used to be a sheet of paper; to accept 5 numbers, a paper form would have 5 fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that in your loop you always instantiate 'index' with 0 therefore the entire array gets the current input instead of just the next cell.
If I understand correctly, your for loop should look something like that:

for (; index < totals.Length; index++) {}

Keep in mind that you'll be limited to 5 inputs (initial size of the array).

Comment: I tried editing the code to match that for statement but it still incurs the same issue. At the end when it displays the array entries it just lists one of the inputs five times

Comment: Taking another look at your code I see that there is no need for the for loop. Just add an if statement checking that the 'index < 5' at the beginning and keep incrementing the 'index' at the end of the 'btnCalculate_Click' method. Usually this is done with a List and an element will be added to it with every click

Comment: That did it, thank you! :D Makes sense now that i'm looking at it, the for loop was never needed.